# What does the colon (:) mean on the command line after a path

Tags: java, bash

I have a java program that uses the Jsoup library to parse some HTML.

To compile the program, I run the command: 
`javac -cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar HtmlVerify.java`, where the jsoup jar is in the same directory.

To run the program, when I run:
`java -cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar HtmlVerify`, I get an error: `Error: Could not find or load main class HtmlVerify`

However, when I append `:` to the jar like so:
`java -cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar: HtmlVerify`, it works.

What is going on here? Why does `:` fix the issue?

Edit: Fixed both `java` commands

Comment: The java command expects the fully qualified name of an executable class as argument. Not the path of a .java file. Your working command can't possibly work. `:` is the standard path separatoron Unix. It's used to separate multiple jar paths in the classpath (or separate directory paths in the PATH environment variable for example)

Comment: Correction: I meant when I run `java -cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar HtmlVerify` I get the error: `Error: Could not find or load main class HtmlVerify`

And it works when I run `java -cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar: HtmlVerify`

Answer (score 5):

The classpath is split on `:`, and each entry is considered a path to search for required classes. **An empty entry will refer to the current working directory**, equivalent to `.`

In other words, your former command meant "Look for classes in `jsoup-1.10.3.jar`".

You latter one means "Look for classes in `jsoup-1.10.3.jar` or alternatively in the current directory".

`HtmlVerify` is in the current directory, so it's only found with the latter command.

The JRE/JDK documentation does not mention this feature, so consider using the more explicit and less confusing `-cp jsoup-1.10.3.jar:.` instead. It was undoubtedly inherited from the same behavior in Unix `PATH`, which POSIX also [asks that you avoid](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03).